# Show/Hide Div with JavaScript based on Select from Triple Dropdown

Tags: javascript

Gang - 
This is my first time posting.  I'm a JavaScript noob - I think I've figured out what direction to take - just not sure how to get there.

I have a triple drop down select menu.  I want the third(final) selection to reveal a hidden div.  Am I on the right track by thinking I need to use a combination of `onchange`, `getElementById` and `if` statements?

The javascript code for the dropdown is Philip M's Cut & Paste Triple Combo box from JavaScriptKit.com.  That work's beautifully.  I won't insert my exact code as the category list is significantly longer.

```
var categories = [];
categories["startList"] = ["Wearing Apparel","Books"]
categories["Wearing Apparel"] = ["Men","Women","Children"];
categories["Books"] = ["Biography","Fiction","Nonfiction"];
categories["Men"] = ["Shirts","Ties","Belts","Hats"];
categories["Women"] = ["Blouses","Skirts","Scarves", "Hats"];
categories["Children"] = ["Shorts", "Socks", "Coats", "Nightwear"];
categories["Biography"] = ["Contemporay","Historical","Other"];
categories["Fiction"] = ["Science Fiction","Romance", "Thrillers", "Crime"];
categories["Nonfiction"] = ["How-To","Travel","Cookbooks", "Old Churches"];

var nLists = 3; // number of select lists in the set

function fillSelect(currCat,currList){
  var step = Number(currList.name.replace(/\D/g,""));
  for (i=step; i<nLists+1; i++) {
    document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].length = 1;
    document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].selectedIndex = 0;
  }
  var nCat = categories[currCat];
  for (each in nCat) {
    var nOption = document.createElement('option'); 
    var nData = document.createTextNode(nCat[each]); 
    nOption.setAttribute('value',nCat[each]); 
    nOption.appendChild(nData); 
    currList.appendChild(nOption); 
  } 
}

function getValue(L3, L2, L1) {
  alert("Your selection was:- \n" + L1 + "\n" + L2 + "\n" + L3);
}

function init() {
  fillSelect('startList',document.forms['tripleplay']['List1'])
}

navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" ? attachEvent('onload', init, false) : addEventListener('load', init, false); 

</script>
```

My HTML is:

```
<div id="menuSearch">
 <form name="tripleplay" action="">
  <p><select name='List1' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List2'])">
   <option selected>-- Topic of Interest --</option>
  </select></p>

  <p><select name='List2' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List3'])">
   <option selected>-- Geographic Area --</option>
  </select></p>
  <select id="info"name='List3' onchange="getValue(this.value, this.form['List2'].value, this.form['List1'].value)">
   <option selected >-- Information Type --</option>
  </select>
 </form>
</div>
```

the divs to show/hide are:

```
<div id="modelingCV">list of publications</div>
<div id="groundwaterCV">list of publications</div>
<div id="subsidenceCV">list of publications</div>
<div id="managementCV">list of publications</div>
<div id="qualityCV">list of publications</div>
<div id="wildlifeCV">list of publications</div>
```

Is replacing the `getValue` in the `onchange` in the final form select with `getElementByID` the best approach?  And replace the `getValue` in the javascript function with some type of `if` statement to specify the values? I am guessing I need to hide the divs with javascript vs CSS?  Am I completely off base all around?

Oy.  Definitely bit off more than I can chew on this one.  Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Comment: I'd recommend using a library like jquery for javascript. It will simplify what you write. http://jquery.com . You won't regret using it. I can't live without it since I learnt how to use it.

Comment: Javi - that's definitely what I'm discovering!  I'm going to research a jquery solution in the meantime.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: +1 for jQuery; why reinvent the function when there's a library..